# SQL - request to find the average loans by user

Tags: sql, request

I am struggling with a SQL request.

I need to find a request to calculate the average loans per user.
I was thinking in doing a **LEFT OUTER JOIN** between the table **SUSCRIBER** and the table **Loan** in order to get all the subscribers even if they have made a loan or not.

Then I have used a **GROUP BY** based on the **IDNumber** of the suscribers to **COUNT** the number of lines. Then I need to get the total numbers of suscribers to calculate the average but by doing this I get 1 or 0 only instead of an average. I don't know what is wrong in this request. Maybe as I have made a group by the IDNumber from the table Loan. How could I get the number of all IDNumber based on this request to make the division ? Thanks

See, the request written in English:

```
SELECT COUNT(Loan.IDNumber) / COUNT(SUSCRIBER.IDNumber), SUSCRIBER.Name AS Name
FROM SUSCRIBER
LEFT OUTER JOIN Loan
ON SUSCRIBER.IDNumber = Loan.IDNumber
GROUP BY Loan.IDNumber;
```

Here are the tables:

> TOPIC(**Code_topic**, Description)
>
> KEY_WORD(**Code_key_word**, keyword)
>
> PUBLISHER(**Code_publisher**, Name, Adress)
>
> AUTHOR(**Code_author**, Name, Surname)
>
> BOOK(**Code_catalogue**, Title, #Code_topic)
>
> COPY (**Code_bookshelf**, Code_wear, Date_aquisition, #Code_publisher, #Code_catalogue)
>
> SUSCRIBER(**IDNumber**, Name, Adress, Phone, Birthdate, Subscription_date)
>
> Loan(**#IDNumber,Code_bookshelf,Loan_date**, Return_date)

Thank you in advance

Comment: The average of what do you need?

Comment: The total number of loans divided by the total number of subscribers = average loans by user. Is that correct?

Comment: Hello @Abra yes indeed, I am looking for the average of books which have been borrowed by a subscriber. This list of person is in the table Loan

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions. I.e. try GROUP BY SUSCRIBER.Name.

Comment: Hello @Charlieface I am looking for the average of books which have been borrowed by a suscriber. The list of suscribers who have borrowed at least 1 book is in the table Loan

Comment: Hello @jarlh thank you for your feedback. And then to get the total number I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: `AVG(COUNT(*) * 1.0) OVER ()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to find a request to calculate the average loans per user.

If you want the average number of loans per subscriber, then you want the total number of loans divided by the number of subscribers.  You can do this with an expression like this:

```
SELECT num_l * 1.0 / num_s
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) as num_s FROM SUBCRIBER) s CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as num_l FROM Loan) l;
```

The `* 1.0` is because some databases do integer division, so `3 / 2 = 1` rather than `1.5`.

Comment: thank you very much for your feedback. I have tested the request but I only get one value. I was tryiing to get the average for each suscriber. Is it possible to mix a group by and then to divide by num_s ? Thank you in advance

Comment: @MathieuSeligmann . . . That is not how I interpret your question.  I don't see how there is an "average" per user.  There would only be a "count".